# how to hide overwrite existing file in rteUploadDialog.aspx in sharepoitn 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I want to uncheck and hide the overwriteexisting file in sharepoint 2010 iam opening the addnew item of a list in a popup as shown below .
where to add the jquery to hide this elements.

[image]

Comment: Did you check this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/4d64ee04-5044-4d3c-a492-9ecd73b9cd9e/i-want-to-remove-overwrite-existing-files-check-from-rteuploaddialogaspx-in-sharepoint-2010?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious

Comment: Hi Madhur I checked that but the pop is from layouts page. my question is where to add the CEWP i tired to add it in editform.aspx but no luck

Comment: I do not have sharepoint in front of me so i cant comment on that. It should be added in the host page. Use Firebug/Dev tools to inspect weather you can see the target element

Comment: I could see the target element  but the question is where to add the CEWP  $('#ctl00_PlaceHolderRteDialogBody_OverwriteFile').hide();

Comment: i am already using a delegate control which has some jquery validation on the newitem popup and when i try to insert the image from a richtextbox in the newitem popup its opening the rteUploadDialog.aspx pop up and i couldn't see my delegate control loading the jquery .if i go to the library of the images and when i try to uplaod a new item its opening upload.aspx dailog and i could see the delegate controls jquery .I could see that both the pages are from _layouts .I am wonderign why my upload.aspx has jquery and rteUploadDialog.aspx is not having the jquery in view source

Answer (score 0):

Without customzing Upload.aspx page, we can uncheck the checkbox and modify the contents of "Overwrite existing file" for a specific library using below steps:

1) Create a js file and refer it in master page.

2) Note down the GUID of library.

3) Add the below code.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
if (location.href.indexOf('2C63AAA5-BC95-41E4-A199-B7658F44736B') >= 0)
{
    $('#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_UploadDocumentSection_ctl05_OverwriteSingle').prop('checked', false);                    
    $("label[for='ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_UploadDocumentSection_ctl05_OverwriteSingle']").text("My Custom"); 
}   
});
```